# Couldn't find method reproducir(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick defined on view class material.textview.MaterialTextView

Tags: kotlin, navigation, viewpager, swiper

Estoy tratando de llamar un elemento que se encuentra en un layout y a través de un adaptador lo asigno a el viewpager pero al momento de llamar el elemento desde el fragment sea el textview o el boton para que a través de un metodo me lleve a otro fragment pero me genera el error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method reproducir(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView with id 'dateTv'

video.xlm

```
<TextView                                
 android:id="@+id/dateTv"                                
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
 android:layout_gravity="end"                                
 android:layout_margin="8dp"                                
 android:background="@drawable/shape_rect"                                
 android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_play"                                
 android:drawablePadding="5dp"                                
 android:gravity="center"                                
 android:padding="5dp"                                
 android:textColor="#000"                                
 android:textSize="8sp"                                
 android:onClick="reproducir"/>

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnplay"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="end"
 android:text="VER"
 android:onClick="reproducir"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
```

VideoFragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val vtv = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_video, null)
        btnplay = vtv.findViewById(R.id.btnplay)
        run = vtv.findViewById(R.id.dateTv)

binding.viewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int,
            ) {
                val titulo = lista[position].titulo.toString().trim()
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), titulo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                
                    }
                })
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }
        })
}

private fun reproducir(view: View) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.videofullFragment)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context for
> android:onClick attribute

**indica que estas llamando un método (reproducir() ) que no existe en el layout .xml que cargas en la Activity o en este caso el Fragment desde donde llamas el método.**

El método debe existir en el layout .xml que cargas desde tu `Fragment`, en este caso si existe en `video.xml` debes cargar este layout:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
    }
```

---

Algo que es muy importante es que el método no debe definirse con el modificador `private`, únicamente debes definirlo de esta forma:

```
fun reproducir(view: View) {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.videofullFragment)
}
```

Comment: Excelente referencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Recuerda que si esta publicación ayudo a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.